# Team Foundation Server: does TFS do the auto merge or the local merge tool?

Tags: version-control, tfs, merge

We're assessing whether to buy either the Standard or Professional version of Araxis merge. The Standard version has no auto merge, but this won't matter if TFS does that for us. But does it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TFS does support auto-merge and, unfortunately, there's no extensibility point that would let you plug-in Araxis' auto-merge functionality (which, to be honest, is probably better than the auto-merge we shipped in TFS 2010). We do have improvements to our auto-merge coming in TFS 11.

Comment: Thanks for your honest answer Jim. For community interest: we are looking at Beyond Compare now, since it seems 3-way compare is needed and this makes Araxis pretty expensive for a team. Although if MS are looking at buying-in a merge solution, Araxis seems the best to me.

Comment: We're building a new diff/merge experience that's integrated into Visual Studio. Check Brian Harry's blog this coming week for more details.